# How to remove the bottom border outline in fab flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, floating-action-button

I want to have a fab in the bottom navigation bar in flutter with a white border. But however there is some kind of a border outline around the icon which I want to get rid of

[image]

As you could see there is some kind of an outline around the button. How can I remove it? This is the code I have written so far,

```
 floatingActionButton: Container(
      height: 70,
      width: 70,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                offset: const Offset(0, -2),
                color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                spreadRadius: 1,
                blurRadius: 2)
          ],
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 6.0),
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: Colors.red),
      child: Material(
          elevation: 0,
          borderOnForeground: false,
          shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
          color: Colors.transparent,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 21,
            ),
          ))),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.call),
        label: 'Calls',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.chat),
        label: 'Chats',
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: do you want just remove half circle border?

Comment: @JahidulIslam yeah even that would be fine I just need to get rid of that outline in the bottom

Comment: you remove `border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 6.0),` from decoration. Let me know if it works for you?

Comment: @JahidulIslam yeah it removes that outline but I want that border :(

Comment: can you share what you actually want?

Comment: @JahidulIslam https://fluttergems.dev/media-cards/fancy_bottom_navigation.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246842/discussion-between-svg-and-jahidul-islam).

Comment: simply remove **boxShadow** from your **BoxDecoration**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest my solution. It works.

```
floatingActionButton: Container(
          height: 70,
          width: 70,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              // boxShadow: [
              //   BoxShadow(
              //       offset: const Offset(0, -2),
              //       color: Colors.grey.shade200,
              //       spreadRadius: 1,
              //       blurRadius: 2)
              // ],
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent, width: 8.0),
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.white),
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: Material(
                elevation: 0,
                borderOnForeground: false,
                shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                color: Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 21,
                  ),
                )),
          )),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.call),
            label: 'Calls',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.chat),
            label: 'Chats',
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Hi, Yeah it works but i need the shadow as well! :(

Comment: In this case, just uncomment boxShadow.

Comment: It works with shadows. I disabled it because it is a simple way to see differences.